# How to get value from php and javascript in another file

Tags: javascript, php

file1.php

```
 <select class="combo-boxs" name="doc_level" id="combo_doc">
    <option value="-">Choose Document Level</option>
    <?php 

       $t=mysql_query("select * from dokumen_level limit 6",$con);

       while($n=mysql_fetch_array($t)){
            if($dok_lvl==$n['nama_dok_level']){$selected='selected';}else{$selected='';}
            $list_dok_level.='<option value="'.$n['nama_dok_level'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$n['nama_dok_level'].'</option>';
            }

            echo $list_dok_level;
            ?>
            </select>


<input  type="text" name="no_document" id="no_document" size="30" disabled="disabled" />


   <script>
     $("select").change(function () {  
       var str =$("#combo_issuer").val();
       var doc =$("#combo_doc").val();

 if(str!="" && doc!=""){ 
    $.get("get_name.php", {issuer: str, doc_lvl: doc}, function(data){
    //get the value from the get_name.php file and asign to display_name text filed
    $("#no_document").val(data.split("-")[0]);
   });
 }
 })
  .change();

 </script>
```

file2.php

```
 $ID = $_GET['issuer'];  
 $doc_lvl = $_GET['doc_lvl'];     

 $sql1= mysql_query("SELECT MAX(id_dokumen) AS maxid from dokumen_internal WHERE issuer='".$ID."'");
 $m=mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
 $id_dok_max=$m['maxid'];

 $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT substring(no_dokumen, 11, 3) AS nomor FROM dokumen_internal WHERE id_dokumen='$id_dok_max' ") or die(mysql_error());
                                   $n=mysql_fetch_array($sql3);
                                   $nomor_max=$n['nomor'];
                                   $no=$nomor_max++;
                                   $no_inc=sprintf("%03s",$nomor_max);

 $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM departemen WHERE id_departemen = '".$ID."'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
 $display="SS/".$doc_lvl."/".$row['id_departemen'].$no_inc;
 echo  "SS/".$doc_lvl."/".$row['id_departemen'].$no_inc;
```

This code was succesfully display what i want.. but i can't get text from that field from no_document

```
<input  type="text" name="no_document" id="no_document" size="30" disabled="disabled" />
```

i want get that value for insert .. May you know where is the bug ? .. Thank you so much ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the field with readonly properties, if you set disabled properties on input tag then it will not be posted.
ex:

```
<input  type="text" name="no_document" id="no_document" size="30" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: yes your're right .. thanks, i just crazy .. but how to make that field disabled and can insert too? any advice ?